# How to Allow MIUI "start in Background" permission for my application

Tags: android, permissions, background, miui

i want "start in Background" permission for open incoming and outgoing call screen when app close.

```
public class CallReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("onReceive","=========>>>>");
    //start activity
    Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), OngoingCallActivity.class);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

}

receiver is opening incoming or outgoing UI screen.but receiver is able to open activity when app in foreground. onReceive method call but receiver not able to open activity when app in background, i try lot's of solution for that but nothing to work.
when manually allow start in background permission it work fine. 

so,how to allow start in background permission in MIUI software.Please help me i spend lot's of day for that.sorry for bad english and thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

For MI device follow below steps

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
            localIntent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
            localIntent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
        startActivity(localIntent);
```

Comment: Any way to check if this is already set?